# Adaboosting in R with any classifier

Tags: r, math, machine-learning, statistics, classification

There is an implementation of `AdaBoosting` algorithm in R. See [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adabag/adabag.pdf), the function is called `boosting`.

The problem is that this package uses `classification trees` as a base or weak learner.

Is that possible to substitute the original weak learner to any other (e.g., `SVM` or `Neural Networks`) using this package?

If not, are there any examples of AdaBoosting implementation in R?

Many thanks!